# Merge javascript with nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript

I'm totally new to all the node shenanigans and don't quite know the best solution for the issue I have, maybe someone can point me towards the best solution towards it.

I have a setup with the framework Buddy to compile [coffeescript](http://coffeescript.org/) into JS, all runs smoothly. What I need now is some tool to merge and preferably uglify and mangle the scripts together into one script.

Buddy has a nice setup where it auto-compiles the scripts upon save, is there such a tool that also watches and does said operations after Buddy has done its thing?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Buddy, but coffeescript supports concatenating the source files with `coffee --join`. Then you would just have to pipe it through uglify, `npm install uglify-js`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a module for node js called [uglify-js](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS) which handles minification

To install it run:

```
npm install -g uglifyjs
```

It will install a command line utility, which accepts files from standard input and outputs to standard output the minified result.

To concatenate you can simply use `cat` command line utility.

You can concatenate all the CoffeeScript files before the minimization or after.

Both have tradeoffs.

By concatenating before, you will avoid dublication of some supporting code that coffeescript generates, but will loose the wrapping to `(function(){ /* your generated code here*/ })()` that CoffeeScript generates to avoid poluting the global scope.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this is what I ended up doing. Made an apple script for this that I run after I have compiled the coffeescript.

Any ideas of solutions to make it run when a file in a directory has changed?

Comment: The `fs` module in node.js itself, which allows you to watch a directory for file changes in it (actually thats what coffee -w does). http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_watch_filename_options_listener   It works nicely on linux but not so well on Mac. Pooling for changes is another option, like recompile everything every 0.5 seconds. You can also use https://github.com/mynyml/watchr which allows to run a command whenever a file changes in a directory

Answer (score 0):

See [brunch](http://brunch.io).
It include builder, linter, concatenator, minifier, source watcher and another useful tools.